# In ggridges, how to colour code points without getting multiple ridges?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggridges, ridgeline-plot

I'm trying to show points on my ridge plot by an index (`PASS` or `FAIL` in this case). But when I do that, I end up with two ridges per group.
I am wondering how to have only one ridge per group?

My code, and the image of output below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)
library(scales)
ggplot(dataSet, aes(x = `Vector_fails`, y = Group, fill = Group)) +
  geom_density_ridges(alpha = .1, 
                      point_alpha = 1,
                      jittered_points = TRUE,
                      aes(point_color = PassCode)) +
  labs(title = 'Vector_fails') +
  scale_x_log10(limits = c(0.09, 1000000), 
                breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
  annotation_logticks(sides="b")
```

[Two ridges per group (but I want one)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5wiT.png)

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example of your code ? see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to plot a ridgeline for each `Group` regardless of `PassCode`. In addition, the the points should be plotted but coloured by the value of `PassCode`.

One possible solution is to plot the ridgelines *without* points and then to add a second layer where the points are plotted but the (then duplicated) ridgelines have been made invisible:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)
library(scales)
ggplot(dataSet, aes(x = `Vector_fails`, y = Group, fill = Group)) +
  geom_density_ridges(alpha = .1) + # plot rigdelines without points
  geom_density_ridges(alpha = 0, # plot points with invisible ridgelines
                      color = NA, 
                      jittered_points = TRUE, 
                      point_alpha = 1, 
                      aes(point_color = PassCode)) +
  labs(title = 'Vector_fails') +
  scale_x_log10(limits = c(0.09, 1000000), 
                breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
  annotation_logticks(sides="b")
```

[image]

#### Data

As the question does not include any reproducible data I have tried to simulate OP's `dataSet`

```
nr <- 1000L
set.seed(1L)
dataSet <- data.frame(
  Vector_fails = sample(9L, nr, TRUE) * 10^sample(c(0:1, 4:5), nr, TRUE),
  Group = sample(c("Normal", "Trial 1", "Trial 2"), nr, TRUE, prob = c(0.8, 0.1, 0.1)),
  PassCode = sample(c("PASS", "FAIL"), nr, TRUE)
)
```